# What's the meaning of "the decadent, twenties feel of the coupes" here?

Tags: meaning-in-context

> All of the women are now drinking champagne out of old-fashioned coupe
>   glasses. Occasionally a fussy guest will request a flute, but most
>   enjoy the decadent, twenties feel of the coupes.[1]

I know that:

- coupe is a "shallow, broad-bowled, saucer shaped stemmed" Champagne
  glass.[2]
- "feel" here is a noun which means " a quality that something has that
  makes you feel or think a particular way about it".[3]
- "decadent"  means "having low moral standards and being more
  concerned with pleasure than serious matters"[4]

But I cannot understand what's the meaning of  "the decadent, twenties feel of the coupes" exactly? Could you expain it to me please?

[1] *An Unwanted Guest* by Shari Lapena

[2] https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Champagne_glass

[3] https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/feel

[4] https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/decadent

Comment: The decade of the 1920s—sometimes called "the Roaring Twenties" or "the Jazz Age"—is often regarded as a period when moral and social standards were dangerously relaxed,  particularly among the young and wealthy.

Answer (score 4):

Some people believe that the correct or "proper" way to enjoy champagne is in a flute glass. So to use coupe is to flout convention, to break the rules, to be decadent. There is also myth that the coupe was designed in the shape of a breast, so even more decadence. So a certain delight in echoing the decadent behaviour of the Roaring Twenties (1920s). Grab a glass and sing ...

*In olden days a glimpse of stocking was looked on as something shocking, now heaven knows, anything goes*. (Cole Porter)

Answer (score 2):

> but most enjoy the decadent, twenties feel of the coupes

The 1920s were a parties decade (it was called the Roaring 20s); the First World War was over, the Great Depression hadn't started yet, the young rich partied hard, as they had nothing better to do.

By drinking their champagne from coupe glasses people feel they are partying like the people of the 1920s, see this link for more detail and pictures:

https://www.thewanakasun.co.nz/news/5171-back-to-roaring-20s.html[image: people enjoying the Decedant 20s feel]